# MATLAB Real Time Plotting Mac OS

Tags: macos, matlab

[EDIT2] I am using the code below to plot a real time signal from serial port.
The issue I have is that the plot lags a lot even though I am not replotting the whole screen. 
How can I speed up the process?

```
function timerCallback(~,~,hObject)
handles = guidata(hObject);
[r,w]=size(handles.y);
if isfield(handles,'s')
try
readasync(handles.s);
n = handles.s.BytesAvailable;
if n > 0
in = fscanf(handles.s,'%d');   
handles.y=[handles.y,in];
guidata(hObject,handles); 
set(handles.h,'yData',(handles.y-99)*26/855);
startSpot = (w)-1000;
axis([ startSpot, (w+50), 0 , 30 ]);
drawnow
end
catch 
end
end
```

Timer is set to fixedRate at 0.001s.

[EDIT2]
I have moved the plot line outside the timer callback. I can't barely see any difference in performance.

Comment: You don't want to be using `plot` every time.  Use it once and create a line, storing the handle to the line (as you are doing for the axis).  Then subsequently just change the ydata for the line.

Comment: `set(handles.axes2,'YData',handles.y);`

Comment: Just did that, didn't change much. What should I do next?

Comment: I measured the amount of time in each line of code and drawnow function is using about 60ms which is much greater than my sampling time.

Comment: [Solved] The axis change was the cause of the problem.